# A question from TIFR GS related to rank of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, problem-solving, matrix-rank

I found this problem in TIFR-GS paper.I have also solved this problem.Can someone please tell me if there are more interesting facts hidden in this problem that needs my attention or which I have missed.I would also like if someone gives me some reference about more such problems.

[image]

**Soln.** Let $x=\begin{bmatrix} 
                       x_1 \\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{bmatrix} 
                       y_1 \\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Notice that $xy^t=\begin{bmatrix} x_1y_1 & x_1y_2 & \dots &x_1y_n\\
                                  x_2y_1 & x_2y_2  & \dots & x_2y_n\\
                                 \vdots & \vdots & \dots &\dots \\
                                 x_ny_1 & x_ny_2  & \dots & x_ny_n\\
                                \end{bmatrix}$

each column is a multiple of the column matrix $x\neq 0$ and at least one column is non-zero as $y\neq 0$.

Suppose,we take $x,y\in \mathbb R^4, x=\begin{bmatrix} 
                       1 \\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{bmatrix} 
                       0 \\
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

So,$A=xy^t=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
                                  0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
                                 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                 0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
                                \end{bmatrix}$

So,rank of $A$ is $1$,so $(d)$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you write is correct and answer is d. For more similar questions you may want to check  "Linear Algebra Problem Book" by Paul Halmos.